# Formatting an amount field into 9(09)V9(06) format via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a requirement where I need to format my input amount field into 9(09)V9(06) format. Our Vendor gave an example like below

*format is 9(09)V9(06) which means **nine digits implied decimal six digits**. If you want to send 124.46 you would send 000000124460000 (Total 15 characters)*

Below is my XML and XSLT I have tried... and it's working right now.
but I just want to check out, is this the right approach for formating amount field into 9(09)V9(06)..? Is there a different way to do it?

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report_entry>
    <amount>124.99</amount>
</report_entry>
```

### XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="report_entry">

        <xsl:variable name="amount_total" select="amount"/>
        <xsl:variable name="amount_total_1"
            select="translate(format-number($amount_total, '#########.000000'), '.', '')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number($amount_total_1), '000000000000000')"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(amount * 1000000, '000000000000000')"/>
```